# How use filter formula in Google Sheet with data contains #N/A

Tags: filter, formula, na

For my example, I have 2 columns A,B in Google Sheet
Column A with list of Stocks symbols like AAPL, IBM, etc....
Column B with simple formula of GOOGLEFINANCE(A2,"price")
Sometimes GOOGLEFINANCE returns error and the cells display #N/A. But this is not my issue...

I would like using filter in column B which show all symbols with prices greater than 100 or #N/A
I prefer not using extra column to achieve that

I'm struggling with it and still didn't find the way to get my result

Just note, my issue isn't GOOGLEFINANCE, It's like example to get the #N/A value

My tought was using filter with formula like: =OR(ISNA(B:B), B:B>100)
But it seems it's ignore the #N/A and doesn't show it

[Link for example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h33-qgPpVzIsklfVI9AcdoOgzc4FWbzAss01HB7vcIw/edit?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: Your link leads to stackoverflow.com…

Comment: Also, I **HIGHLY** recommend you **do not** give everybody edit access. Instead, make your link read only and have people recommend you edits here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Due to me having edit access, I’ve edited the document to be view only (to prevent any damage from being done)

Comment: Thanks again @Fastnlight, appreciate it ! But still waiting for a good solution for my issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my question I tried the formula "=OR(ISNA(B:B), B:B>100)"
But I must know that if Google Sheets "see" cells with N/A on this column - The result is automatically N/A, even if I put the ISNA in the first condition

So to solve it I used a formula like this:
=IF(ISERROR(B:B), TRUE, B:B>100)

I updated the sheet if someone wants to check it